# Laravel4 Date based actions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Mysql Table with columns below

```
ID  Amount Charge_Date
1   200    12-Apr-2015
2   300    10-May-2015
```

I am trying to write code so that when date reaches today, the amount is debited in a new table. eg lets say today is 12 Apr then Rs 200 is debited to account which is a new table.

Please help me with the idea. Should I set a Cron Job which will run everyday and check if date is today. Or is there a better way of calculating such things.

Also need help with setting recurring events like everyday I need to calculate outstanding from a table and send email to customers.

Comment: I can't see how this is a laravel question or php at all. If you are using a php script to invoke a stored procedure or function in mysql, mind that php has to be invoked by another process, or be an always running process itself. If you are going to handle this in your database, there are options like cron jobs or triggers. non of them can guarantee that your demand is done lightening fast as it hits the next day since computation world is deterministic and quantified, but the difference will not be noticeable in most cases. PS: triggers make your database slow if you mind the tps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron seems to be the only way out. Just need to set cron from cpanel and it will run for any desired controller